# How to see the ser file which we have saved in android in private mode?

Tags: android, macos, file, path

I have written some data in a file in android by this code

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tempdata.ser",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(map1);
oos.close();
```

Now I want to confirm by checking that file. So is there any way to see this file mannualy in MAC system. Also tell me that I want to make the file in such a manner that if file exist my data should be appended otherwise create a new file, so my code is correct or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to confirm by checking that file. So is there any way to see this file mannualy in MAC system.

On the emulator, you can browse to `/data/data/your.app.package.name.goes.here/files` using DDMS.

> Also tell me that I want to make the file in such a manner that if file exist my data should be appended otherwise create a new file, so my code is correct or not?

I am not aware that this is possible with Java serialization, mostly because few people actually use Java serialization.